# Should I use Function base view or Class base view in Django ? Can anyone explain please

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework, django-views

Confused on what I should use which has better control

I have tried both & I feel Class based view is easier to write So Can anyone explain me how I should proceed & when to use class based view &   Function based views or can I use them together